# R Function to Populate Data Frame Based on Conditions in Separate Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a blank data frame 'DF1' that looks like this:

| Site | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 03:00:00 | 2021-01-01 06:00:00 | 2021-01-01 09:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BMA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| BMC | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| MCA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| MCC | NA | NA | NA | NA |

I have a section data frame 'DF2' that looks like this:

| ImageDate | SiteName |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 02:53:00 | BMA |
| 2021-01-01 08:44:00 | MCC |
| 2021-01-01 05:22:00 | BMC |

How can I query DF2 so that when a data point in 'ImageDate' falls into one of the column headers (time slots) of DF1 a number '1' is placed in the corresponding/matching 'Site' of DF1? And if no data is found in a particular column (time slot) for a site, that cell gets a '0', so that it would yield the following data frame:

| Site | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 03:00:00 | 2021-01-01 06:00:00 | 2021-01-01 09:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BMA | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| BMC | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| MCA | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| MCC | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a blank `df1` and filling it you can transform `df2` in a way that it gives the structure that we want.

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df2 %>%
  mutate(ImageDate = floor_date(ymd_hms(ImageDate), '3 hours')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ImageDate, values_from = ImageDate, 
              values_fn = length,values_fill = 0)
```

Comment: This mostly worked based on the question I posted. However, the example is much reduced compared to my actual data set. In the actual data set my 'DF1' runs for 83 columns of consecutive data/time slots, some of which won't get data from 'DF2', but are still just as important. If there's a way to proceed using both DF1 and DF2, that would be better for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You may add a `complete` step after `mutate` and before `pivot_wider` step to include the missing times. For example, if you want to include all 3 hour interval from 1st Jan 2021 to 1st feb 2021 you can do `mutate (...) %>% complete(ImageDate = seq(ymd_hms('2021-01-01 0:0:0'), ymd_hms('2021-02-01 0:0:0'), by = '3 hours')) %>% pivot_wider(....)`

Comment: You sir are a saint. This worked great. I'm buying you a coffee.